# How are conditional "<capability> if <capability>"-type dependencies resolved by RPM?

Tags: rpm, dependencies

On inspecting dependencies of RHEL8 packages, I recently came across the following dependency statement:

```
~$ rpm -qpv --requires cockpit-ws-264.1-1.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm 
post: (policycoreutils if selinux-policy-targeted)
manual: (selinux-policy >= 3.14.3-95.0.1.el8 if selinux-policy-targeted)
...
```

I understand the `or` type requirement statements, but how does the RPM package management process `if`-type dependencies?

- In the above example, does it mean that `policycoreutils` is only a requirement if `selinux-policy-targeted` is already present in the target system?
- Likewise, is `selinux-policy` only required if `selinux-policy-targeted` is already installed? Or is it the version requirement (`>= 3.14.3-95.0.1.el8`) that only applies if `selinux-policy-targeted` is installed (although that would deviate from the meaning in case of `or`-type requirements)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`a if b` is equivalent to `a or not(b)`](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/blob/2a8d89a1c390e6ca1de0ece49aa11012b1d0ff89/lib/depends.c#L735), so yes, `policycoreutils` is only a requirement if `selinux-policy-targeted` is installed.

The `if` operator applies to the whole dependency, so `selinux-policy >= 3.14.3-95.0.1.el8` is only required if `selinux-policy-targeted` is installed.

`if` in this context is a boolean operator in RPM, and is documented in [the Boolean Dependencies section](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/boolean_dependencies.html) of [the RPM Reference Manual](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/).